# Wordpress orderby query sometimes not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been looking for the error for a while and have no idea what could be causing it.

In about 80% of the time the following code works, but sometimes it just orders completely random:

```
function filter_where($time, $where = '') {
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time)) . "'";
$where .= " AND post_status = 'publish' ";
return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');

$array = array(
    'cat' => 2,
    'meta_key' => 'ratings_score',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'ratings_score',
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 6
);

filter_where($time);

query_posts($array);
```

The filter function works. I have tested it with different `$time` values and post_status's.

Could it just be some kind of lag or have I ordered the code in a wrong manner?
some posts do not have a `meta_key` of `ratings_score`, but all posts in cat = 2 do have this `meta_key`.

Maybe this has something to do with the issue?

Comment: Make sure you call wp_reset_query either right before each time you execute your query, or just after.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **never** use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

You should be using `WP_Query` or `get_posts` and **only** when you cannot achieve the results you are after by modifying the main query with `pre_get_posts`

You are correctly adding your filter before your query arguments, but then you are again adding the function again after the query arguments. I believe this is one of the big problems here. You should remove the filter after the query arguments, not re-adding them

Replace this line

```
filter_where($time);
```

with

```
remove_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

One final note, why are you defining `$time` but then you doesn't use it at all?